# specify array list type from an attribute

Tags: java, arrays, class, arraylist

imagine the i have three classes

```
Feedback
Customer
Supplier
```

now i have a pagination code that it's only for feedback class

```
    public ArrayList<Feedback> generatePage(int currentPage,Class paginator_type)
    {
        int startItem=currentPage*ITEMS_PER_PAGE;
        int numOfData=ITEMS_PER_PAGE;
        ArrayList<Feedback> pageData=new ArrayList<>();

        if (currentPage == LAST_PAGE )
        {
            for(int i=startItem;i<startItem+ITEMS_REMAINING;i++){
                String ss[] = all_data[i].split(" ");
                pageData.add(new Feedback(ss[5],ss[3],ss[4],ss[0]));

            }
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i=startItem;i<startItem+numOfData;i++)
            {
            String ss[] = all_data[i].split(" ");
            pageData.add(new Feedback(ss[5],ss[3],ss[4],ss[0]));

            }

        }
        return pageData;
    }
```

now i need the arraylist type to change depanding of what type of objects iam adding to it
i need to make only one method that accepts any type of array list , how can i do it ? and how i can make a parameter that accepts a class type
for example :

call method :

```
makeArrayList(1,Reservation);
```

method :

```
public void makeArrayList(int i , Class class) <- how i can declare the parameter
ArrayList<class> aa = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Write an interface and have all three classes implement it, then stop caring about "what specific type of classes might exist" and instead write your code for that interface. Any class that implements it will now work.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans can i have more explanation sir ?

Comment: Sure, but not from me. Have a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html, interfaces are part of basic Java, and you should probably read up on how to use them from a good book or tutorial rather than from a Stackoverflow comment or answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define an `interface` and implement in the classes that you want or `abstract` class and extend it.

example

```
public interface IBase { }

public class Feedback implements IBase {}
public class Customer implements IBase {}
public class Supplier implements IBase {}
```

and in this method change class to be:

```
public void makeArrayList(int i , IBase parent)
```